# The Integral Values For Which The Expression Is A Perfect Square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, pell-type-equations

> Given that x is an integer, when does the expression $4x^2 + 80$  form a perfect square?

I tried putting $x=4$, got a perfect square but i am not able to calculate how many such cases can be there?

Is there any general approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:**

Set $4x^2 + 80 = y^2$. Then we have $4x^2 - y^2 = -80$. Factor it as a difference of two squares and go through all the pairs of divisors of $-80$, whose product is also $-80$.